How to diagnose USB device not being picked up properly?
I'm trying to get a device (ultrasound scanner) connected to my machine via USB. The device is custom built hardware, I'm not sure of the details - however I think it uses FTDI601Q.
The manual I have received instruct to install following instructions from https://ftdichip.com/drivers/d3xx-drivers/.
$ sudo dmesg --follow
...
[10425.343602] usb 1-5: can't set config #1, error -71
[10425.343862] usb 1-5: USB disconnect, device number 49
[10425.787026] usb 1-5: new high-speed USB device number 50 using xhci_hcd
[10456.540313] usb 1-5: New USB device found, idVendor=0403, idProduct=601f, bcdDevice= 0.00
[10456.540325] usb 1-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[10461.661231] usb 1-5: can't set config #1, error -110

Output of lsusb -t is as follows:
$ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 001.Port 001: Dev 001, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/16p, 480M
    |__ Port 001: Dev 038, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 001: Dev 038, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 005: Dev 050, 480M
    |__ Port 009: Dev 031, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/5p, 480M
        |__ Port 001: Dev 032, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 001: Dev 032, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 002: Dev 033, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
        |__ Port 002: Dev 033, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
        |__ Port 004: Dev 034, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/5p, 480M
            |__ Port 003: Dev 036, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=r8152, 480M
            |__ Port 005: Dev 037, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=[none], 480M
        |__ Port 005: Dev 035, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=[none], 480M
        |__ Port 005: Dev 035, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 480M
/:  Bus 002.Port 001: Dev 001, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/9p, 20000M/x2

I am running the following kernel:
$ uname -a
Linux guines 6.6.36-1-lts #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu, 27 Jun 2024 12:26:27 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux

There are some instructions in the manual to do
rmmod ftdi_sio
rmmod usbserial # This fails claiming builtin.

modprobe ftdi_sio

However these haven't turned out to be of much help.
What would be a way to debug/diagnose what the issue is from here?

Have you compiled and modprobe'd the driver? You cannot diagnose much if the built-in kernel drivers do not support it.
